# No route matches [GET] "/products"

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-4, versioning

i follow this [How To](https://medium.com/@alexfedoseev/isomorphic-react-with-rails-part-ii-614980b65aef#.6ri2vl9am) but i have No route matches error...

i have this routes.rb:

```
# config/routes.rb

require 'api_constraints'

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/' do

    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      resources :products, only: [:index, :show, :create, :destroy]
    end

  end

end
```

Rake Routes:

```
api_products GET    /products(.:format)     api/v1/products#index {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
             POST   /products(.:format)     api/v1/products#create {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}

api_product GET    /products/:id(.:format) api/v1/products#show {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
            DELETE /products/:id(.:format) api/v1/products#destroy {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
```

This is the error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/products")
```

Comment: Show you error, when you get it, and add your `routes.rb` code to question.

Comment: There are the links in my description...

Comment: If at any time somebody reads your question here and (heaven forbid) github is no more. he/she cannot fully understand your question.

Comment: @Matthias , i have fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that the request is getting rejected at subdomain constraint. I think you make request to http://localhost:3000/produtcts, but you need some url like **http://api.****/products**. There is a guide how to do it locally http://shapeshed.com/developing-subdomain-rails-sites-locally/

Comment: I presume that the request is getting rejected at subdomain constraint. I think you make request to http://localhost:3000/produtcts, but you need some url like http://api.****/products. There is a guide how to do it locally http://shapeshed.com/developing-subdomain-rails-sites-locally/
I've updated my answer above